# Output character limits for SUM

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I adjust the below so the output auto adjusts to the correct numbers of characters?

```
  TO_CHAR(
      SUM("Sales_Value") + SUM("Tax_Rate"), '$9,999,99.99')
      AS "Full Sales Total"
```

Right now, it is giving me $1,000,000 as the default whether the number TOTAL is $1M or less than $1M.

This is what I get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiV1I.png)

Answer (score 1):

Increase your format `'$9,999,99.99'` (for example `'$999,999,99.99'`). This format specifies how Oracle turns a number into a string. If the width of the format is smaller than what the number requires, Oracle fills the available space with `#` (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html)

Comment: Thanks. That helps. Any idea why the math is coming out wrong?